# Convert base64 string to png image with python

Tags: javascript, python, django, base64

I'm working on a Django application where the user can trigger the webcam with javascript and snap a picture. This picture is stored in a canvas. I want to retrieve this image with python as a base64 string, convert that into a png file and save it into the Django server. This is my code so far

HTML Template

```
<center>
    <button type="button" name="button" class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg' id='start'>Start Video Capture</button>

    <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video><br>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#image_model" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
</center>

<center>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
</center>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Retake</button>
<form class="image_to_server" action="{% url 'img_submit' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="base64Field" value="" id='base64'>
    <input type="submit" value="Use Image" class="btn btn-primary" id="use_image">
</form>
```

Javascript Code

```
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');
// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

$('#start').click(function() {
    // Get access to the camera!
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true
        }).then(function(stream) {
            //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }

    $('#snap').fadeIn();

    // Trigger photo take
    $('#snap').click(function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        $('#base64').val(dataURL)

        $("#use_image").click(function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        });
    });

});
```

Django views.py

```
def img_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data =  request.POST.get('base64Field')
        byte_data = base64.b64decode(data)
        image_data = BytesIO(byte_data)
        img = Image.open(image_data)

    return HttpResponse(data)
```

I am getting an "incorrect padding error" for the python code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Or how to rectify this error.

I followed this [link](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3400#issuecomment-428104239) to write the python code.

Comment: as the error says, check your padding (make sure your b64 string is correct). take note that its edited a little in the link you provided

Comment: I am sending the data directly from js to django without working on it before. So not sure how the base64 string could be wrong. any help???

Comment: print it and look at it, even add it(tag as code) to your question so we can look at it

Comment: do you want me to print the entire base64 string. I am a beginner and do not understand base64 yet. I am also not able to add the entire base64 string to stackoverflow

Comment: you can also print it in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and provide a link

Comment: exceeding limit in pastbin. any other way to post the string???

Comment: lets try something simpler. print the first and last 10 characters

Comment: FIRST 10 `data:image` LAST 10 `VORK5CYII=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not remove the header from your string, which means its not just the b64 data
if you look in your example you will see these lines

```
import re
base64_data = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', data)
```

once you remove the header, you should be able to use your string as b64

 the header im speaking of looks like this `data:image/png;base64,`